# Iterable throws NoSuchElementException even after I have verified by printing each element

Tags: java, lazy-loading, guava, iterable, nosuchelementexception

I have a bunch of `Map<Integer, TreeSet<Double>>` objects, and I am passing the values off to another method. I got a `NoSuchElementException` in that method, so started debugging, and saw that the call to `Map#values()` throws this exception. But, when I loop through the values, it prints all the values perfectly. Here's the code snippet that's causing this issue:

```
Map<Integer, TreeMultimap<String, Double>> kMap = Maps.newTreeMap();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    TreeMultimap<String, Double> treeMultimap = TreeMultimap.create();
    treeMultimap.putAll("a" + i, Lists.newArrayList(0.0, 0.06, 0.17, 0.23));
    treeMultimap.putAll("b" + i, Lists.newArrayList(0.0, 0.16, 0.34, 0.49));
    kMap.put(i, treeMultimap);
}

Map<Integer, TreeSet<Double>> rescaledKMap =
    Maps.transformEntries(kMap, ToRescaledValueMap(1.2));

Iterable<TreeSet<Double>> treeSets = rescaledKMap.values();

// Prints out each element correctly. No exception is thrown.
for (TreeSet<Double> set : treeSets)
    System.out.println(Joiner.on(',').join(set));

// NoSuchElementException thrown in getMeanPlot() before anything happens there.
TreeMap<Double, Double> mean_rescaledKMap = 
    getMeanPlot(rescaledKMap.values());
```

The signature is `getMeanPlot(Iterable<TreeSet<Double>>)`.

How is the iterable correct just before it gets passed to the second method, but throws an exception just as the second method start?

**Stack Trace**

The stack trace shows the `Maps.EntryTransformer` object `ToRescaledValueMap` as the culprit. Here's the trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1113)
    at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1151)
    at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1146)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$Itr.next(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:1145)
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.min(Ordering.java:460)
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.min(Ordering.java:479)
    at DistributionMetricExperiment$6.transformEntry
```

Does this have anything to with Guava's lazy initialization? I can write my own little method instead of using the `Maps#transformEntries` method, but not knowing the reason behind this bug is ... well ... bugging me. The entry transformation is as follows:

```
static Maps.EntryTransformer<Integer, TreeMultimap<String,Double>, TreeSet<Double>>
ToRescaledValueMap(final double interval_length) {
    return new Maps.EntryTransformer<Integer, TreeMultimap<String,Double>, TreeSet<Double>>()
    {
        public TreeSet<Double> transformEntry(Integer i, TreeMultimap<String,Double> mmap) {
            double mmap_min = Ordering.natural().min(mmap.values());
            double mmap_max = Ordering.natural().max(mmap.values());
            TreeSet<Double> rescaledValues = Sets.newTreeSet();
            for (double val : mmap.values())
                rescaledValues.add(interval_length * (val - mmap_min)/(mmap_max - mmap_min));
            return rescaledValues;
        }
    };
}
```

*Edit*:

- I don't know whether this matters or not, but wanted to add that I have also issued the same print statements (the for loop over `Iterable<TreeSet<Double>` in the above code) as the first statement of `getMeanPlot`. Even there, it prints alright, and then throws the exception.
- My apologies for the use of underscore in variable names. The variables are reflecting subscripts I have been using in the maths behind my code. I am aware of the naming convention, but in this code I was more focused on having the ability to recognize the mathematical meaning of a variable just by looking at it.

Comment: Please stick to [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), please use `camelCase` for variables and use meaningful names. This code is like... well... _code_.

Comment: Can you come up with an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that someone else (with Guava) could run to reproduce the issue? Also, what version of Guava?

Comment: It's Guava 16.0.1. A short example is kinda hard for me to generate, but let me try to come up with something.

Comment: @PaulBellora : Changed the code and added the entry transformation code. I haven't checked whether this reproduces the same bug, but it's as close (to the real data) an example I could create.

Comment: You use `Ordering.natural().min()` on an empty `TreeMultimap<String,Double> mmap`. You only print a `TreeSet<Double> set`

Comment: You didn't show the `getMeanPlot` method. Since I was able to execute your code (filling in my own `getMeanPlot` method) without issue, I'm guessing something was messed up there.

Comment: @ogregoire : Can you please post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you print the `TreeSet<Double> set` and this misleads you into thinking that your collection is populated. Because your error is not on `set` but rather on `TreeMultimap<String,Double> mmap`: you execute `Ordering.natural().min(mmap)` and that's where the issue is coming from. Guava specifies that looking for the min (or max) element in an empty collection will result in throwing a `NoSuchElementException`, which is what you have here.

Comment: This bug has certainly taught me to be more careful. I was checking for null elements, but I never checked for empty sets. Lesson learned :)